# Github Actions Remote SSH to Digital Ocean VPS Issues

Tags: ssh, github-actions, digital-ocean

I am using https://github.com/appleboy/ssh-action in a actions worflow. Below is the example workflow I am using. It is trying to SSH into my Digital Ocean box but it keeps timing out. So I launched a cheap Digital Ocean box to see if this code would work against it. Turns out that the below code works against this temporary box.

Any ideas on what my Digital Box is doing to prevent connection? I am able to SSH into it from the terminal on my computer with no issue. Port 22 is listening.

```
name: remote ssh command
on: [push]
jobs:

  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: executing remote ssh commands using password
      uses: appleboy/ssh-action@v0.1.7
      with:
        host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
        username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.PASSWORD }}
        port: ${{ secrets.PORT }}
        script: whoami
```

Comment: Did you try using `ping`, `telnet`, `dig`, `traceroute`, etc. from GitHub Actions to check if the machine is reachable? And, did you try to connect [using a private key](https://github.com/appleboy/ssh-action#using-private-key)?

Comment: good catch on ping, yes ping is not working via the workflow (hangs). Like I said I can SSH from any machine however.

Comment: Right. `ping` may be disabled too. What about `telnet` on SSH port (22)? Is that connectable?

Comment: Doesn't work via workflow, ping/telnet works from any other machine.

Comment: Right. I'll try to test this on my side and update here later.

Comment: Thanks, its just weird that a new droplet works just fine. I can't see any networking setup that would prevent connection to this box via the workflow.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Could you please confirm if you tried to set up a connection [using a private key](https://github.com/appleboy/ssh-action#using-private-key)?

Comment: No, I have a password.

Answer (score 0):

you can try my config

```
#FIRST OF ALL DO THIS( SKIP IF YOU ALREADY DO THIS )
#Generate an SSH Key
# ssh username@host.com
# cd ~/.ssh
#ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"

# Adding the Public Key to authorized_keys in server, so runner will be accessed with private key 
# cat github-actions.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Adding the private key to your repository’s secrets
# create secrets in repo with name SSH_PRIVATE_KEY with value is cat from private key that we generate earlier


name: Deploy to server

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
      - action

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      # Adding the Private key to a Github Actions Workflow
      - name: Install SSH Key
        uses: shimataro/ssh-key-action@v2
        with:
          key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
          known_hosts: unnecessary

      # Adding a correct known_hosts value
      - name: Adding Known Hosts
        run: ssh-keyscan -H ${{ secrets.SERVER_IP }}  >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts

      - name: Deploy application
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.SERVER_IP }}
          username:  ${{ secrets.SERVER_USERNAME }}
          port: ${{ secrets.SERVER_PORT }}
          key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
          script: |
            cd newBlogs
            pm2 stop app
            git pull origin master
            npm install
            npm run build
            mv .env.example .env
            pm2 start server.js --name app
```